# How to restrict the Name field to just a few names in HTML?

Tags: html

```
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name" pattern="[Catherine]">
<br>
```

i want the above code to allow only Catherine to be entered into the field but not sure where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your pattern should be

   ```
   pattern="Catherine"
   ```

   without the square brackets, which have a special meaning in RegEx.

   If you want to allow multiple names, use this RegEx pattern:

   ```
   pattern="(Catherine|Katie|Kate)"
   ```
2. This is a validation that only works on submitting a form. It does not prohibit typing in other names. If the pattern doesn't match, the browser won't submit the form and show an error popup next to the input instead.

**Example with only Catherine allowed:**

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="Catherine" required />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Example with multiple names allowed:**

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="(Catherine|Katie|Kate)" required />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If you really want to only allow that particular word to be entered, consider using JS with an `onInput` event handler. However this doesn't look like anything you really want.

---

**EDIT:** I have also added the `required` keyword which prevents an empty input from being submitted.

Comment: Thanks the above code did work for me, i am new to HTML , just learning.

Comment: If i need to allow more then one name, how would i put it in the pattern attribute?